# What is the Latin word for “polymath”?

Tags: word-request

I wonder what Latin word or expression best describes a polymath, someone who masters several subjects. The two solutions I thought of are the following but I find them unsatisfactory.

- polymathēs, -is
- homo universalis

The first one because it is simply a transliteration of the Greek and I am not able to find any Latin text using it.
The second one because the meaning is wrong, I don't mean an omniscient man but simply one who has several areas of competence.

Comment: Well, it worth to note here, that there is the proverbial expression *Omnis minervae homo* which [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=minerva&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) renders as "Jack of all trades"

Comment: @d_e With a couple citations, that itself might make a decent answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not have a complete and satisfying answer, but digging around revealed a couple of points of interest:

- Johan Wower wrote [*De Polymathia tractatio: integri operis de studiis veterum*](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_QWVA4EYdY6cC/page/n7/mode/2up) in 1665.
  He uses the word *polymathia* throughout the text, but I did not spot a word for a polymath.
  The text is available in [plain text](https://archive.org/stream/bub_gb_QWVA4EYdY6cC/bub_gb_QWVA4EYdY6cC_djvu.txt), but the quality of the conversion is pretty low.
  He might have a suitable word somewhere in there.
- A lot of online sources (including your question!) seem to give the Latin expression ***homo universalis***, but I managed to find no Latin texts that use this expression.
  I am unsure whether it is simply a translation of the Italian 'uomo universale'.
  At any rate, this expression is a decent choice: easy to understand and clearly Latin.
- The prefix *poly-* is Greek, and the corresponding Latin one would be *multi-*.
  This is very productive, as there are loads of Latin words starting with this.
  I would not even consider coining a new word with this prefix out of the question.

  The L&S entry for *[multiplex](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=multiplex&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059)* gives examples like *vir multiplex in virtutibus*.
- A good general word for (innate) ability is *ingenium*.
  Combining with my previous point, I think ***vir/femina/homo ingenii multiplicis*** would be a decent option.

Comment: Thank you very much for your research, I will consider different options but multiplex is definitely one of them

Comment: @KimP I'm glad you found it helpful! *Multiplex* is indeed a good building block, but I don't think it'll work alone here.

Comment: Probably not but I was referring to your last point, not the word alone, sorry for the unclarity. Anyway, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In the medieval scholastic community one very early word for a polymath was *doctor universalis* and it was applied to [Albertus Magnus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albertus_Magnus) and [Alan of Lille](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alain_de_Lille). Later the Catholic church regularized the title and applied it to various scholars.